# How to use bash conditionals correctly

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I want to only do some code if $# equals 1 and $1 is a readable existing file.
I have following code:

```
if [[ $# -eq 1 ] -a [ test -r $1 ]]
```

I have tried many different solutions for an and statement.
Like

```
[ $# -eq 1 ] $$ [ test -r $1 ]
[ $# -eq 1 -a test -r $1 ]
```

and many more...

Nothing seems to work. I think its because of the test command.
Sometimes I get an error like **test not found** or **too many arguments** or smth else

My whole code:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 1 ] -a [ test -r $1 ]]
then
groupadd -f "TAI12A"
IFS=:
while read nachname vorname klasse
do
nutzername=$nachname$vorname
groupadd -f $klasse
useradd -g "TAI12A" -G $klasse -s /bin/bash -m -p "taipasswd $nutzername
done < $1
else
echo "Uebergabewerte fehlerhaft"
fi
```

Comment: `if [[ $# -eq 1 ] -a [ test -r $1 ]]` --- WTF??? That's not right. Pick one or the other `[[...]]` or `[...]`, but there is no such thing as `[[..][..]]`. Now `[ $# -eq 1 ] && test -r $1` would work or `[[ $# -eq 1 ]] && test -r $1` would also work. `'test` is a alias of `[..]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want to use `test`, then no brackets:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ] && test -r "$1" ; then
    do this ...
fi
```

Note: `[` is a command, it's an alias for `test` with one exception: when using `[` instead of `test`, `]` must be the last argument.

To illustrate this: even if bash nowadays includes `[` as a builtin command, the command `/usr/bin/[` should still exist on your server.

PS: I would just use:

```
if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ -r "$1" ] ; then
    do this ...
fi
```

which is the same as

```
if test $# -eq 1 && test -r "${1}" ; then
    do this ...
fi
```

---

Further confusion might be added by the fact that bash also has an extended conditional expressions in the form `[[ ... ]]`. I recommend to read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions